# Are the observables in Angular Guard completed after navigation?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-routing

Example

I'm in './home' and I would go in './user-data' if I'm authenticate
(lazy-loaded route)

I'm authenticate and the Guard with Observable say True and I go in './user-data'

I do something in './user-data'

Now i logout and I want that is the Guard to take me out './user-data' and not a redirect on logout function, but...

so look-like that the Observable in the Guard, if I am allready in the route, is completed and not emit others values, in this case null

right? that observable in the guard... is it completed?
I hope in my poor english and in you

Comment: Did you meant you want to be logged out and it is only logging out after u reload?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then yes. The guard is only executed when the route is activated. It won't watch for other changes and re-execute unless the route is again activated. You can turn on watching route events in the console with `{enableTracing: true}` so you can see these events occur.

Comment: thanks Deborah, yes! I was looking for this: "The guard is only executed when the route is activated" but my dubt is on the Observable in the canActivate, if it is an hot Observable  after the route is actived the Observable  not emit value anymore? is it completed?
I'll play with enableTracing, grazie again

thanks also to Akhi

Comment: @vincenzo.na did you found a solution for this?